# GoToDefinition used to show result in a split window, but now uses buffer

Tags: buffers, vim-windows, plugin-you-complete-me

I have this mapping in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap gd :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration
nnoremap gf :tab split \| YcmCompleter GoToDefinition<CR>
```

When I press `gd`, it writes the command `:YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration` for me and on Enter, I used to get a split window with the definition I'm looking for in there.

Somehow, randomly or after me pressing certain keys (which I don't know exactly what), the split no longer happens. It's strange because I didn't change configs, and it simply switched to showing result in a full-screen new buffer, without split.

Anyone knows what I might have pressed or why this is happening?

Comment: Did you update? Sometimes plugins change

Comment: Nope, I installed everything manually and this happened without any update or change to configs.

Comment: Im afraid i dont know whats happening. You could try the debug command (or the verbose switch). Is it a new tab, or the window is the only one?